# Sending Multiple Words to Another Program

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

How would I output a sentence with VB.NET?

Example: Your program and Internet Explorer are open, your program outputs "http://stackoverflow.com" and presses "{ENTER}", and it will go to the page.

Example: An auto-talking bot for MSN.

Comment: BTW, your question has nothing at all to do with the fact you're using the Express Edition. You still have full access to all of .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "send a string to a running program", I think you're looking for [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx2k26ca%28VS.90%29.aspx)

**Edit**

SendKeys takes a string argument (that's why it's named Send**Keys**, not Send**Key**), so yes, you can send "sentences".

Comment: I knew about SendKeys, but can you send sentences with it?

(SendKeys.Send("Blablabla"))